# SQL Server one table or two?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Suppose I have two entities that have similar fields but differ in a couple of them. For example

```
public class Foo{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public int IndexNumber{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Info{get;set;}
}
```

versus

```
public class Bar{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public DateTime AppointmentTime{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Info{get;set;}
}
```

In Entity Framework you could actually put ID, Name, and Info into a third parent class and have the other two inherit from it, and have it automatically store them together in one table with a "discriminator" column that spells out the class names to distinguish them.

My question is, assuming that there are no relationships between the two models (foreign keys and whatever), is it better to do one table with nulls and a discriminator, or two tables?

Comment: I would not put them in the same table as they are not the same thing.

Comment: A database should be designed using database rules for good design. Mixing up different entities in a table isn't good design at all. A database table is not an Excel sheet. It represents either an entity or a relation

Comment: And putting multiple sets of data in one Excel sheet usually is not a good idea either!

Comment: everything true, but... sometimes rules can be "not observed" (this is what I think).  Moreover, it depends: if you have other similar "objects", using a single table with a "discriminator" column, can allow you to make simpler query who concerns more "objects" (es. COUNT of record for "object" type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to think about entities not from physical storage perspective, but from domain. Different entities, which apply different business rules and not related to each other, should be stored separately.

Even if `Foo` and `Bar` entities have the correlating fieldset at the moment, they could serve for different purposes. And do not forget about entities invariants, which can differ (e.g. `Name` field in `Foo` class could contain only name, but `Name` in `Bar` also should contain last name. It is synthetic example, but should point the difference, even if both fields are strings)

Comment: Good points. I would also add that in the future both classes could evolve in different, unrelated ways, which may needlessly complicate DB design if they're keep in the same table.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use 2 tables, or to be exact, the **Table per Concrete class**. You can view the different approaches in depth in this link:
[Inheritance Strategy in Code-First](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)